# finding the max in a dataframe with multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Please i need help
i'm new to pyspark and i got this probleme
i have a dataframe with 4 columns like this

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | 2 | E1 | 2 |
| O1 | 3 | E1 | 1 |
| O1 | 2 | E1 | 0 |
| O1 | 5 | E2 | 2 |
| O1 | 2 | E2 | 3 |
| O1 | 2 | E2 | 2 |
| O1 | 5 | E2 | 1 |
| O2 | 8 | E1 | 2 |
| O2 | 8 | E1 | 0 |
| O2 | 0 | E1 | 1 |
| O2 | 2 | E1 | 4 |
| O2 | 9 | E1 | 2 |
| O2 | 2 | E2 | 1 |
| O2 | 9 | E2 | 4 |
| O2 | 2 | E2 | 2 |

and i  want to have this ( the max of D for each (A,C) couple) :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O1 | 2 | E1 | 2 |
| O1 | 2 | E2 | 3 |
| O2 | 2 | E1 | 4 |
| O2 | 9 | E2 | 4 |

i tried

```
table.groupby("A","C").agg(round(max("D")))
```

it did work by the column B is missing

Comment: You need A C couple, so B will always be missing, as it is not needed. Please imagine situation where you have several identic A,C, but different B. You either have to also include B in groupBy (but you said you don't want it), or you need to use some aggregation function on this column if you want to see some value for B

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but is there any other way to add column B to my dataframe

Comment: You should learn window functions

Comment: How are you determining what value of B to take?

Comment: B depends on the other columns A, B and C

Comment: `B depends on the other columns A, B and C ` - this makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use partition by instead of group by, that way you can keep all your columns. You will retain all your records.
Edit added- If you want the distinct values of A,C - just get the columns you want and get unique values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
table1 = table.withColumn("max_D",F.round(F.max('D').over (Window.partitionBy('A','C'))))
table1.select('A','B','C','max_D').distinct().show()
```

Comment: i tested this code but it didn't work, i still have doubles of A and C

Comment: select the relevant columns and take distinct values.

Comment: i did study about window partitioning and i did add a dropDuplicates on specific columns and it did work, thank you 

Comment: import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
table1 = table.withColumn("max_D",F.round(F.max('D').over (Window.partitionBy('A','C'))))
table1.select('A','B','C','max_D').dropDuplicates(['A','C','max_D']).show()

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to apply `max` with pair of `D` and `B` so you won't lose `B` when aggerate.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .groupBy('a', 'c')
    .agg(F.max(F.array('d', 'b')).alias('max_d'))
    .select(
        F.col('a'),
        F.col('c'),
        F.col('max_d')[1].alias('b'),
        F.col('max_d')[0].alias('d'),
    )
    .show()
)

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  c|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
| O1| E1|  2|  2|
| O1| E2|  2|  3|
| O2| E1|  2|  4|
| O2| E2|  9|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: thank you, this works much better, i just want to ask if there is a way to do max(d) with only the couple (a,c) and then join the result with the first table to obtain theire values of b